# Get slice indices from mask Python

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have an `(N,)` array of floats (`arr`), but I only care about the entries that are >= a given `threshold`. I can obtain a mask like this:

```
mask = (arr >= threshold)
```

Now I want an `(N,2)` array of the corresponding slice indices.

For example, if `arr = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]` and `threshold = 1`, then `mask = [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True]`, and I want the indices `[ [2, 5], [6, 8], [9, 10] ]` (which I can use as `arr[2:5], arr[6:8], arr[9:10]` to obtain the segments where `arr >= threshold`).

Currently, I have an ugly for loop solution that follows each stretch of `True` before appending the corresponding slice indices to a list. Is there a more concise and readable way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compute a list of start and end indexes using the mask by comparing mask booleans to their successors.  Then join the starts and ends to form ranges (all vectorized using numpy methods):

```
import numpy as np

arr       = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
threshold = 1
mask      = arr >= threshold

starts    = np.argwhere(np.insert(mask[:-1],0,False)<mask)[:,0]
ends      = np.argwhere(np.append(mask[1:],False)<mask)[:,0]+1
indexes   = np.stack((starts,ends)).T

print(starts)  # [2 6 9]
print(ends)    # [5 8 10]
print(indexes)
[[ 2  5]
 [ 6  8]
 [ 9 10]]
```

If you want the result in a Python list of tuples:

```
indexes = list(zip(starts,ends))  # [(2, 5), (6, 8), (9, 10)]
```

If you don't need (or want) to use numpy, you can get the ranges directly from arr using groupby from itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

indexes = [ (t[1],t[-1]+1) for t,t[1:] in 
            groupby(range(len(arr)),lambda i:[arr[i]>=threshold]) if t[0]]

print(indexes)
[(2, 5), (6, 8), (9, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools groupby with the `key` parameter, along with `enumerate` to get the groupings.  If the group values are all `True` you can take the first and last+1 values.

```
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
threshold  = 1


idx = []
for group,data in groupby(enumerate((arr >= threshold)), key=lambda x:x[1]):
    d = list(data)
    if all(x[1]==True for x in d):
        idx.append([d[0][0], d[-1][0]+1])
```

Output

```
[[2, 5], [6, 8], [9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) and [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html):

```
indexes = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.append(arr >= threshold, 0))) + 1
indexes = list(zip(indexes[0::2], indexes[1::2]))
```

Output:

```
>>> indexes
[(2, 5), (6, 8), (9, 10)]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when arr is [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1].